# Label of a checkbox disappearing when it is unchecked in chrome(only)

Tags: html

I have created checkbox along with its label. When I check the checkbox, a div appears below and when I uncheck it, it should disappear. 
My problem here is, when I uncheck the checkbox, the label is also getting disppeared. And this happens only in chrome.
Can anybody help me know the root cause of this issue.

My Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script>
    function change() {
      {
        if (document.getElementById("abc").style.display == 'none') {
          document.getElementById("abc").style.display = 'block';
        } else {
          document.getElementById("abc").style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="AUTO" id="AUTO" onclick="change();">
    <label id="AUTOMATIC" for="AUTO">
      Checkbox Label.
    </label>
    <div id="abc" style="display:none;">
      Hi
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Weird!! Looks like webkit rendering glitch. I tried webkit force render method but didn't work. Note that clicking anywhere restores label. Cannot reproduce in Canary branch of chrome though

Answer (score 0):

Add following lines, this solves issue

```
    } else {
      document.getElementById("abc").style.display = 'none';
    }

    document.getElementById("AUTOMATIC").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("AUTOMATIC").offsetHeight ;
    document.getElementById("AUTOMATIC").style.display = '';
  }
```